# relative pfad in Zend_Pdf_Image doesn´t work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

In my PdfController I want to print logos whose paths come from my database.

I tried like follows:

```
$pfad = ".". $logen->logo;
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($pfad);
$page->drawImage($image, $posX-30, $posY, $posX+30, $posY-30);
```

It doesn't work --> I get a time out.

Afterwards I wanted to know if I really get the right path:

```
$pfad = ".". $logen->logo;
$page->drawText($pfad, $posX, $posY +11,'UTF-8');
```

I get a path: ./images/logos/Berlin_1.png which is the right one.

If I try with the absolut path, it works:

```
$pfad = ".". $logen->logo;
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('./images/logos/Berlin_1.png');
$page->drawImage($image, $posX-30, $posY, $posX+30, $posY-30);
```

Where is the error, must be the same with the relative path?

Answer (score 0):

This statement: `$pfad = ".". $logen->logo;` does not work correctly. Now I added the . to the paths in my database records and it works.

If somebody knows, why the statement isn't working it might be helpful.